# Update the value of a selected object in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wand to select an option from a multiple select field and update the prozent value of the selected objects:

```
<div id="assistenzen">
<form>
    <select v-model="assistenz" multiple>
      <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option">
        {{ option.text }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(assi, prozent) in assistenz">{{assi.text}}
            <input v-model="assistenz" v-bind:value="prozent">
            {{assi.prozent}}
        </li>

    </ul>
</form>
</div>


<script>

var assistenz = new Vue({
  el: '#assistenzen',
  data: {
    assistenz: 'keine Assistenz',
    options: [
      { text: 'One', value: 'A', prozent: '0' },
      { text: 'Two', value: 'B', prozent: '0' },
      { text: 'Three', value: 'C', prozent: '0' }
    ]
  },
});
assistenz.config.devtools = true
</script>
```

This code creates an input for each selected option but, the whole option text is stored in the input as value. Also it does not update the property of the object.

Comment: I didn't get what is issue, but there is few things you have to pay attention.
1. `assistenz` is stored as string, and you tried to use array.push on it.
2. You are trying to iterate over `assistenz` which is still string.

Comment: Ok I want assistenz be replaced with one ore multiple of the options and in the next step update the prozent value of the selected options.

Comment: `v-model` is already binding the value.. it doesn't make sense to also use `v-bind:value`. Not really sure what behavior this would cause if you have both.

Comment: Ok iam not sure how to update the properties of the elements of the array - I can update a property of the whole array but how do I access one of the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently i prefer 'watch':

```
watch: {
  multiselect: function(indexes) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++) 
      this.options[i].show = indexes.indexOf(i) > -1;
    }
}
```

full example:

https://jsfiddle.net/4xq3mj9o/

Answer (score 1):

To update the value of the choosen objects I had reverenze the Item iterated in the for loop and bind the input model to the items value:

```
<div id="assistenzen">
<form>
    <select v-model="assistenz" multiple>
      <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option">
        {{ option.text }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="assi in assistenz">{{assi.text}}
            <input v-model="assi.prozent">
            {{assi.prozent}}
        </li>

    </ul>
</form>
</div>


<script>

var assistenz = new Vue({
  el: '#assistenzen',
  data: {
    assistenz: 'keine Assistenz',
    options: [
      { text: 'One', value: 'A', prozent: '0' },
      { text: 'Two', value: 'B', prozent: '0' },
      { text: 'Three', value: 'C', prozent: '0' }
    ]
  },
});
assistenz.config.devtools = true
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [vue-multiselect](https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect)

Just use something like this

```
<Multiselect :options="Options" :value="Values" :multiple="true" @update="updateMultiValue"> </Multiselect>
```